# Can a predicate contain quantifier

Tags: logic

Use the facts that the negation of a $\forall$ statement is a $\exists$ statement and that
the negation of an if-then statement is an and statement to rewrite the following statement
without using the words necessary and sufficient.

> The absence of error messages during translation of a computer program
>   is only a necessary and not a sufficient condition for reasonable
>   [program] correctness.

My attempt: By rewriting the given statement, we obtain

$\forall$ computer program, it translates without error messages is only a necessary and not a sufficient condition for reasonable [program] correctness.

Denote $A$: A computer program translates without error messages

$B$: A computer program is correct.

So the given statement can be separated into two parts, they are:

$\forall$ computer program, $B \implies A$ (necessary)

$\neg(\forall$ computer program, $A \implies B$) (not sufficient)

Then the answer is:

For all computer program $P$, if $P$ is correct, then it translates without error messages. However, $\exists$ a computer program $P$ such that $P$ translates without error messages and is not correct.

Question: Why can't I let $A$ be $\forall$ computer program, it translates without error messages? If I do this, then I got the second sentence wrong, which is $\forall$ a computer program $P$ such that $P$ translates without error messages and is not correct. The only difference is the quantifier.

Comment: With your (slightly revised) formalization, we have : $\forall p(B(p) \to A(p)) \land \lnot \forall p (A(p) \to B(p))$. If so, what is exactly your question ? It seems to me that the exercise ask you to rewrite at least the RHS "moving inside" the negation ...

Comment: Regarding the title, a *predicate* letter of the language is simply a symbol : $P,Q,R$ (examples from math : $<, \in$ both *binary* predicate symbols) and thus it cannot contain a quantifier. But we can have *formulae* with one or more free variables that defines relations : e.g. $x \le y$ can be defined as : $\exists z(y=x+z)$. In this case, we have a formula with a quantifier expressing a relation.